# Listen to PostgreSQL NOTIFY events with Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

Can I use Slick / Play Framework (Scala) to listen to PostgreSQL NOTIFY statements?

I want to do something similar to this:

http://bjorngylling.com/2011-04-13/postgres-listen-notify-with-node-js.html

Comment: Does this help ? http://www.smartjava.org/content/listen-notifications-postgresql-scala

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think Slick supports [PostgreSQL's `NOTIFY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-notify.html), but the [postgresql-async](https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async#listennotify-support-postgresql-only) library does. One can use the latter to create an Akka Streams `Source` and incorporate it in a Play endpoint that streams the database notifications to a client:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

import akka.actor._
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

import com.github.mauricio.async.db.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnection
import com.github.mauricio.async.db.postgresql.util.URLParser
import com.github.mauricio.async.db.util.ExecutorServiceUtils.CachedExecutionContext

import play.api.Logger
import play.api.http.ContentTypes
import play.api.libs.EventSource
import play.api.mvc._

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await

@Singleton
class DbNotificationController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents,
                                         materializer: Materializer)
  extends AbstractController(cc) {

  implicit val mat = materializer

  val configuration = URLParser.parse("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5233/my_db?user=dbuser&password=pwd")
  val connection = new PostgreSQLConnection(configuration)
  Await.result(connection.connect, 5 seconds)

  val (actor, dbSource) =
    Source.actorRef[String](Int.MaxValue, OverflowStrategy.dropNew)
          .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink[String])(Keep.both)
          .run()

  connection.sendQuery("LISTEN my_channel")
  connection.registerNotifyListener { message =>
    val msg = message.payload
    Logger.debug(s"Sending the payload: $msg")
    actor ! msg
  }

  def index() = Action {
    Ok(views.html.scaladbnotification())
  }

  def streamDb() = Action {
    Ok.chunked(dbSource via EventSource.flow).as(ContentTypes.EVENT_STREAM)
  }
}
```

In the above controller, when the listener receives a notification from the database, the payload (a `String`) in the notification is logged and sent to an actor. The messages that are sent to this actor feed the `Source` that is used in the `streamDb` endpoint. Before the payload messages are sent to the client, they're converted to Play's [`EventSource`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.EventSource$) class.

---

I adapted `DbNotificationController` from the [Play streaming example application](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-streaming-example), which you can use to experiment. If you would like to do so, obviously you need to integrate `DbNotificationController` into that project:

1. Add `"com.github.mauricio" %% "postgresql-async" % "0.2.21"` to `build.sbt`.
2. Set up PostgreSQL as needed, including the `NOTIFY`, and adjust the database URL in the controller according to your configuration.
3. Copy and paste `DbNotificationController` into `/app/controllers/`.
4. Copy the following file (call it `scaladbnotification.scala.html`) into `app/views/`:

```
@main {

    <h1>Server Sent Event from DB</h1>

    <h1 id="db"></h1>

    <p>
        DB events are pushed from the Server using a Server Sent Event connection.
    </p>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        if (!!window.EventSource) {
            var stringSource = new EventSource("@routes.DbNotificationController.streamDb()");
            stringSource.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
                $('#db').html(e.data.replace(/(\d)/g, '<span>$1</span>'))
            });
        } else {
            $("#db").html("Sorry. This browser doesn't seem to support Server sent event. Check <a href='http://html5test.com/compare/feature/communication-eventSource.html'>html5test</a> for browser compatibility."); 
        }
    </script>    
}
```

5. In the `/conf/routes` file, add the following lines:

```
    GET /scala/dbNotification           controllers.DbNotificationController.index()
    GET /scala/dbNotification/liveDb    controllers.DbNotificationController.streamDb()
```

6. Start the application with `sbt run` and navigate to the following URL in your browser:

   http://localhost:9000/scala/dbNotification